# Не работает обработчик события KeyDown, C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Уже задавал такой вопрос, но ответа нет: не обрабатывается событие KeyDown. Вот сам обработчик:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString());
}
```

Сообщение не выводится, в чём может быть проблема? Функция подписана на событие.

Comment: Не нужно было повторно создавать аналогичный вопрос. Нужно было отредактировать предыдущий, он бы поднялся наверх, появился бы в топе, на главой странице сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Ну значит вы не подписались на событие, сделайте так:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}
```

Либо через вкладку События у формы `Form1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: tCode, функция подписана на событие. Я подписался и через вкладку, и как показали вы, всё равно ничего.

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий а `MessageBox` хоть появляется?

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий я проверил, у меня работает

Comment: Andrei, в том то и дело, что ничего не появляется.

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFLiY.png

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий покажите скрин где вы подписаны на событие?

Comment: А, MessageBox появляется, но когда нажимаю на стрелки, ничего не появляется. То есть, я просто нажимал по своей глупости только на стрелки, с ними кажется KeyDown не работает (хотя у них тоже есть свои коды), вот я и подумал что событие не обрабатывается. Ладно, сейчас разберусь, спасибо всё равно.

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий стрелки так же работают

Comment: У меня все клавиши кроме стрелок работают.

Comment: @АрсенийКривецкий - Вероятно, нажатия клавиш со стрелками обрабатываются где-то ещё, что успевает их перехватить раньше. Добавьте в вопрос информацию: какие ещё события у вас есть, какие компоненты размещены на форме и пр.